# Place in a file from drop down list

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How would you find out the position in a text file of an option selected from a drop down box?
I have got a text file of different values stored on new lines. I then load this into an array which forms the values of a drop down box. I would like to know the line position of the value selected by the user. My code so far is included below.

```
from tkinter import *


class search():
def __init__ (self, master):

  self.master = master
  self.master.title("Search For Quotes Screen")
  self.master.geometry("2100x1400")
  self.master.configure(background = 'white')

  self.master.configure(background = "white")
  self.Title = Label(self.master, text = "Quote Retrieval", font = ("calibri", 20), bg = "White")
  self.Title.place(x=650, y = 10)


  array=[]#initialises array
  with open('PostCode_File.txt', 'r') as f:# opens name of your file
      array= [line.strip() for line in f]#puts values of file in array. each line = one part of array
  f.close()



  Option = StringVar()
  Option.set("Please select postcode of quote")
  self.options = OptionMenu(self.master, Option, *array)#creates drop down menu
  self.options.config(bg = 'navy', fg='white', font =('calibri', 20))
  self.options["menu"].config(bg="Navy", font=('calibri', 13), fg= 'white')
  self.options.place(x=100, y=100)

  print( self.options.get())
```

I have noticed a drop down box doesn't have the function like a text entry box or maybe im using it wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your values unique?

Comment: The majority of values are but there may be some values which are the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique lines in your input file, you can accomplish this by keeping a reference to your option array and then calling `index` on that array to get the position of the selected item. Note that the `get()` function is not on the `OptionsMenu` object; it's on the `StringVar` object, which means you'll need to keep a reference to that as well. For example:

```
from tkinter import *


class Search():
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Search For Quotes Screen")
        self.master.geometry("2100x1400")
        self.master.configure(background='white')

        self.master.configure(background="white")
        self.Title = Label(self.master, text="Quote Retrieval", font=("calibri", 20), bg="White")
        self.Title.place(x=650, y=10)

        with open('foo.txt', 'r') as f:  # opens name of your file
            self.array = [line.strip() for line in f]  # puts values of file in array. each line = one part of array
        f.close()

        self.option = StringVar()
        self.option.set("Please select postcode of quote")
        self.options = OptionMenu(self.master, self.option, *self.array)  # creates drop down menu
        self.options.config(bg = 'navy', fg='white', font =('calibri', 20))
        self.options["menu"].config(bg="Navy", font=('calibri', 13), fg='white')
        self.options.place(x=100, y=100)

        self.button = Button(master, text='OK', command=self.on_ok)
        self.button.place(x=100, y=150)

    def on_ok(self):
        value = self.option.get()
        print(value, self.array.index(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = Tk()
    search = Search(master)
    mainloop()
```

This won't work, though, if the lines in your input file are not unique.